# Lock The Dock On Multiple Screen Setup

Tags: macos, dock

I like all the multiple screen features in Mavericks except one.

I HATE the hit cursor to the bottom of the screen to move the dock. I've searched hi an low for a way to stick the dock to one spot. I'd even buy a product.

There must be a way to say "Dock stick to Screen 2" or 1 or whatever. I have already read that you can go back to the old behavior of multiple screens, but then I loose the other features.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: Did you ever get it working?

Comment: Nope. I looked for a paid solution as well. Someone needs to create this!